# Date SQL to get 31st August

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to get the last 31st August every year dynamically.
E.g if current date is today I would like to get 31st August 2019
next year, and I want this to be dynamic and get 31st August 2020?

I have tried `Date_Sub` and `Date_Trunc` and they are not working. Any ideas would be really helpful?

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(current_date(), INTERVAL 5 DAY) as five_days_ago
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below will always return last /latest August 31st

```
#standardSQL
SELECT IF(CURRENT_DATE() < last_august_31, DATE_SUB(last_august_31, INTERVAL 1 YEAR), last_august_31) AS last_august_31 
FROM UNNEST([DATE(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE()), 8, 31)]) last_august_31
```

In case if you need to use this within the query with date field - consider below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT DATE '2019-01-01'dt UNION ALL 
  SELECT '2019-12-31' UNION ALL 
  SELECT CURRENT_DATE()
)
SELECT dt, IF(dt < last_august_31, DATE_SUB(last_august_31, INTERVAL 1 YEAR), last_august_31) AS last_august_31 
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST([DATE(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM dt), 8, 31)]) last_august_31
-- ORDER BY dt
```

with result

```
Row dt          last_august_31   
1   2019-01-01  2018-08-31   
2   2019-12-31  2019-08-31   
3   2020-02-25  2019-08-31
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with dates as (
  select cast('2019-01-01' as date) as my_date union all select '2019-12-31' union all select current_date()
)

select
  my_date,
  date(extract(year from my_date) - case when extract(month from my_date) < 9 then 1 else 0 end, 8, 31) as prev_aug_31,
  date(extract(year from my_date) + case when extract(month from my_date) >= 9 then 1 else 0 end, 8, 31) as next_aug_31
from dates
```